# Facebook php call get friends gender

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Graph Api to load all friends of the current user of my Facebook App, but I actually only want the females. The only solution to that I have found till now is to loop over all the friends and do a Graph-call for every single friend (uid).

But this takes AGES! (+/- 1 second per friend, so 200 seconds for someone with 200 friends..) Is there a way to get the friends gender quicker?

Comment: You could maybe manage something with [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), but I don't know exactly how and don't have spare time to experiment at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use 1 graph api call to get all friends.
2. Collect facebook ids of all the friends,you can use this graph api call to get gender of all friends at once:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=123456,464566,1222333&fields=name,gender&access_token=aaaaaaa|asdadasdadasdasd.1-565073384|sdfsdfiouuoiUIOIUoiuUI

Here is the documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Whole thing including 2 calls will take around 2-5 seconds at max.

Answer (score 2):

You can just query the 'user' FQL table:

`SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and sex='female'`

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

The current APIs support FQL and pure graph API calls so they should live side by side in your app with no issue.